# Signapk.jar giving error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder

Tags: java, android, apk

I have tried to make my app system app and i converted successfully on my windows machine but when I tried to run following same command on mac machine it kept on giving *error*. I have downloaded **signapk.jar** from different sources as well not able to run the command.

```
java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 device-owner.apk device-owner_sign.apk
```

*Error*:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
        at com.android.signapk.SignApk.addDigestsToManifest(SignApk.java:169)
        at com.android.signapk.SignApk.main(SignApk.java:325)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the app you're trying to run isn't JDK 9 compatible.

Try again using Java SE 8.